# How to get count 0 even data is not exist in table?

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I'm stuck on this sql query. I want to get all records described in condition even if it does not exists in table. I want to get result like that.

```
 +-----------------+
 | total |  rating |
 +-----------------+
 | 0     |    5    | 
 +-----------------+
 | 0     |    25   |
 +-----------------+
 | 1     |    50   |
 +-----------------+
 | 3     |    75   |
 +-----------------+
 | 0     |    100  |
 +-----------------+
```

I'm tried to use `COUNT` function get the result. The rating is always `5,25,50,75,100`.

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(SurveyAnswer.rating) AS total,rating 
 FROM survey_answers AS SurveyAnswer INNER JOIN surveys AS Survey ON 
 SurveyAnswer.survey_id = Survey.id WHERE SurveyAnswer.survey_id = '33' 
 AND SurveyAnswer.rating  IN (5,25,50,75,100) 
 AND SurveyAnswer.organisation_id = '26742' 
 GROUP BY SurveyAnswer.rating) tbl
```

Current result is shown

```
 +-----------------+
 | total |  rating |
 +-----------------+
 | 1     |    50   |
 +-----------------+
 | 3     |    75   |
 +-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
SELECT A.RATING, IFNULL(RC,0) AS TOTAL_RATING
 FROM (SELECT 5 AS RATING UNION ALL SELECT 25 UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION ALL SELECT 75 UNION ALL SELECT 100) AS A
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT RATING, COUNT(*) AS RC 
            FROM survey_answers 
            INNER JOIN surveys AS Survey ON  SurveyAnswer.survey_id = Survey.id 
            WHERE SurveyAnswer.survey_id = '33'
            AND SurveyAnswer.organisation_id = '26742' 
             GROUP BY SurveyAnswer.rating) B ON A.RATING = B.RATING
```

Answer (score 1):

try **Left join** instead of **inner**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, appreciate your help :)